# How to update access db by editing datagridview cells?

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to edit items after inserting to access by clicking the save button? How can i save the edits done in datagridview rows to access?

Already tried the update query
For each loop

```
vb.net 

Private Sub BunifuFlatButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuFlatButton1.Click

        Dim constring As String = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\Users\PU-IMO\Desktop\BlueWavesIS - Copy\BlueWavesIS\BlueWavesIS.accdb")
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(constring)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Using con As New OleDbConnection(constring)

                'nettxt.Text = (grosstxt.Text * perdistxt.Text / 100) - (dislctxt.Text + disusd.Text + distax.Text)


                Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Update PurchaseInvoice set [Itemnum] = @ItemNum, [Itemname]= @ItemName, [Itemqty]= @ItemQty, [Itemprice] = @ItemPrice, [discount] =@discount, [subtotal] = @subtotal,[Preference] = " & preftxt.Text & ", [Suppnum] = " & pnumtxt.Text & ",  [UniqueID] = " & pautotxt.Text & " Where [UniqueID] = " & pautotxt.Text & "", con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", row.Cells("ItemID").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", row.Cells("ItemName").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemQty", row.Cells("ItemQty").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemPrice", row.Cells("ItemPrice").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", row.Cells("discount").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subtotal", row.Cells("subtotal").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ref", preftxt.Text.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Suppnum", Convert.ToInt32(pnumtxt.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniqueID", Convert.ToInt32(pautotxt.Text))
                DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        Next

'This the code i used to show the data in datagridview:
Private Sub NewPurchaseInvoice_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\Users\PU-IMO\Desktop\BlueWavesIS - Copy\BlueWavesIS\BlueWavesIS.accdb"
        con.Open()
        Dim sql As String = "Select [Itemnum],[Itemname],[Itemprice],[ItemQty],[discount],[subtotal] from PurchaseInvoice where [UniqueID] = " & pautotxt.Text & ""
        Dim cmd10 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Sql, con)
        'Dim adap As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select [Itemnum],[Itemname],[Itemprice],[discount],[subtotal] from PurchaseInvoice where UniqueID = " & pautotxt.Text & "", con)
        'Dim ds As New System.Data.DataSet
        'adap.Fill(ds, "PurchaseInvoice")

        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd10.ExecuteReader
        Do While dr.Read()
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr("ItemNum"), dr("ItemName"), dr("ItemQty"), dr("ItemPrice"), dr("discount"), dr("subtotal"))
        Loop
        con.Close()
```

I expect that all the rows will be updated as each other, but the actual output is that each row has different qty name etc...

Comment: Bind it to datagridview as source, then when you call an .Update it will update only the changed cells.

Comment: How to do the bind process?

Comment: Please add the code where you fill the DataGridView to your question. You will probably want to use a DataAdapter.

Comment: @Mary I added the code used to fill the datagridview

Answer (score 0):

This code does not seem appropriate in the load event because `pautotxt.Text` will not have a value yet. Can you move it to a Button.Click?

I guessed that the datatype of ID is an Integer. You must first test if the the .Text property can be converted to an `Integer`. `.TryParse` does this. It returns a `Boolean` and fills `IntID` that was provided as the second parameter.

You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. The `Using...End Using` blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error. You can pass the Select statement and the connection directly to the constructor of the command.

ALWAYS use `Parameters`, never concatenate strings to avoid sql injection. Don't use `.AddWithValue`. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications

The DataAdapter will open the connection, fiil the `DataTable` and close the connection if it finds it closed; however if it is found open it will leave it open.

The last line binds the grid to the `DataTable`.

```vb
Private Sub FillGrid()
    If Not Integer.TryParse(pautotxt.Text, IntID) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")
        Return
    End If
    dt = New DataTable()
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(Sql, con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = IntID
            Dim adap = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            adap.Fill(dt)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

DataTables are very clever. When bound to a `DataGridView` they keep track of changes and mark rows as update, insert, or delete. The DataAdapter uses this info to update the database. Once the database is updated we call `.AcceptChanges` on the `DataTable` to clear the marking on the rows.

```
Private Sub UpdateDatabase()
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, cn)
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = IntID
            Using builder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
                da.Update(dt)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    dt.AcceptChanges()
End Sub
```